# Running am command in terminal emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to play streaming videos from the terminal emulator using `gallery3d` app via `am` command in my Galaxy S5, here is the command I used:

```
am start -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity udp://239.255.42.40:5004
```

but I get this error:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=udp://239.255.42.40:5004 cmp=com.android.gallery3d/.app.MovieActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: startActivity asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; 
this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)        
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1426)        
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2367)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Then I found [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/54187/97787) answer which tells

> add the `--user 0` option to your `am` command

Therefore I run below command :

```
am --user 0 start -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.gallery3d.app.MovieActivity udp://239.255.42.40:5004
```

But I get `bad component name : --user`

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?
My android version is 4.4.2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need place `--user` after `start` because it is a sub-command argument, I think.